# How to use apply function with rolling window such that it returns multiple values in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, rolling-computation, sliding-window

Here I have a Series and I want to slide a window of size 4 rows over the series. Only if first and last element of window is 1, I want all elements in that window to be converted to 1. Else the window remains as it is. Like in series below when window will be over index 2-5, zeroes are converted to 1.

| Index | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 |
| 14 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 |

I want output as

| Index | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 |
| 14 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 17 | 1 |

I tried using,

```
def assign(rows):
   if (rows[0]==rows[-1]) and (rows[-1]==1):
       rows = rows.replace(to_replace = 0, value = 1)
       return rows
   else:
       return rows
df['column A'].rolling(4).apply(assign)
```

However, rolling in combination with apply requires me to return scalar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite mathematical approach to that:

- take the cumulative sum over the Column A, (this makes the start indexes uneven ans stop indexes even)
- by taking Modulo 2 you will set the start indexes to 1 and the stop indexes to 0
- Combine that with the Column A to find out which values were actually stop points (and not just 0 in the beginning)
- Assign the values if the lengths match

```py
df["cum_A"] = pd.cumsum(df["Column A"])
df["mod_A"] = df["cum_A"] % 2
start_indexes = df["mod_A"] == 1
stop_indexes = (df["mod_A"] == 0) & (df["Column A"] != 0)

if len(start_indexes) == len(stop_indexes):
    for i in range(len(start_indexes)):
        df["column_A",start_indexes[i]:stop_indexes[i]] = 1
```

There could definitely be some speed improvements with vectorization, but this gets the job done.